# Gateway responding with ACK instead of server. Causes RST

Tags: networking, macos, home-networking, tcp, asuswrt

I have a service running on my LAN which works very intermittently. It serves a webpage just fine right after I restart the server running macOS 14.1 (I noticed this happening on multiple versions of 13.0 as well). But after a few hours, I cannot connect to it anymore on any device on my LAN, as I get a connection reset error in any browser I use. I noticed that the SYN between the client and server functions as normal, but as soon as I perform a GET, my gateway responds with an ACK, causing my client to send an RST. My gateway is running AsusWRT. When the page is working, my gateway doesn't respond.

My client is at 192.168.50.228, and the server is at 192.168.50.42.

| No. | Time | Source | Destination | Source MAC | Destination MAC | Protocol | Length | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9154 | 4.932032 | 192.168.50.228 | 192.168.50.42 | Client | Server | TCP | 78 | 54054 → 8080 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=64 TSval=1633977301 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM |
| 9155 | 4.937303 | 192.168.50.42 | 192.168.50.228 | Router | Client | TCP | 78 | 8080 → 54054 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=64 TSval=1803376346 TSecr=1633977301 SACK_PERM |
| 9156 | 4.937396 | 192.168.50.228 | 192.168.50.42 | Client | Server | TCP | 66 | 54054 → 8080 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131712 Len=0 TSval=1633977306 TSecr=1803376346 |
| 9157 | 4.937488 | 192.168.50.228 | 192.168.50.42 | Client | Server | HTTP | 543 | GET / HTTP/1.1 |
| 9158 | 4.941333 | 192.168.50.1 | 192.168.50.228 | Router | Client | TCP | 66 | 8080 → 54054 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=2051 Len=0 TSval=1803376351 TSecr=1633977306 |
| 9159 | 4.941385 | 192.168.50.228 | 192.168.50.1 | Client | Router | TCP | 54 | 54054 → 8080 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0 |
| 9160 | 5.047863 | 192.168.50.228 | 192.168.50.42 | Client | Server | TCP | 517 | [TCP Retransmission] 54054 → 8080 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131712 Len=477 TSval=1633977417 TSecr=1803376346 |
| 9161 | 5.053608 | 192.168.50.42 | 192.168.50.228 | Router | Client | TCP | 54 | 8080 → 54054 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0 |

On the server side, I never see the gateway's IP address, only the ACK it sends after the GET, which makes me think the gateway is intercepting the ACK and responding on behalf of the server.

| No. | Time | Source | Destination | Source MAC | Destination MAC | Protocol | Length | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1935 | 9.542822 | 192.168.50.228 | 192.168.50.42 | Client | Server | TCP | 78 | 54054 → 8080 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=64 TSval=1633977301 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM |
| 1936 | 9.543382 | 192.168.50.42 | 192.168.50.228 | Server | Router | TCP | 78 | 8080 → 54054 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=64 TSval=1803376346 TSecr=1633977301 SACK_PERM |
| 1937 | 9.543747 | 192.168.50.1 | 192.168.50.42 | Router | Server | ICMP | 106 | Redirect (Redirect for host) |
| 1938 | 9.548315 | 192.168.50.228 | 192.168.50.42 | Client | Server | TCP | 66 | 54054 → 8080 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131712 Len=0 TSval=1633977306 TSecr=1803376346 |
| 1939 | 9.548317 | 192.168.50.228 | 192.168.50.42 | Client | Server | HTTP | 543 | GET / HTTP/1.1 |
| 1940 | 9.548480 | 192.168.50.42 | 192.168.50.228 | Server | Router | TCP | 66 | 8080 → 54054 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=478 Win=131264 Len=0 TSval=1803376351 TSecr=1633977306 |
| 1941 | 9.551754 | 192.168.50.228 | 192.168.50.42 | Router | Server | TCP | 54 | 54054 → 8080 [RST] Seq=478 Win=0 Len=0 |
| 1942 | 9.658227 | 192.168.50.228 | 192.168.50.42 | Client | Server | TCP | 543 | [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 54054 → 8080 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131712 Len=477 TSval=1633977417 TSecr=1803376346 |
| 1943 | 9.658367 | 192.168.50.42 | 192.168.50.228 | Server | Router | TCP | 54 | 8080 → 54054 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0 |
| 1944 | 9.658987 | 192.168.50.1 | 192.168.50.42 | Router | Server | ICMP | 82 | Redirect (Redirect for host) |

Comment: A router would not intercept local traffic, even though it could in certain circumstances. // Looking only at the IP addresses is not enough. MAC addresses are highly relevant on local traffic. Also make sure to perform a packet capture on the Mac in question and compare the two.

Comment: I've updated it to include the server side. The server sends packet 1940, and the client receives that packet at 1958, but its source is the router, and not the server, which seems to be why the client then sends an RST. I'm trying to come up with a reason why the router would do this, or a feature I should look for to enable/disable.

Comment: Like I said, the MAC addresses. // Also, I see at least two ICMP redirects that should not be occurring at all in local network communications.

Comment: The client's destination is always the server's MAC address except for the RST where it's the router's MAC address as seen from the client.

The server is responding to the client with the MAC address of the router for some reason instead of of the client.

I checked the ARP table on the server, and it looks like the IP address of the client has the client's MAC address, so I'm not sure why it would choose the router as the destination.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere! Check the Mac's routing table and subnet mask for irregularities.

Comment: The routing table shows the client's IP as the client's MAC address according to `arp`, not the router's, and the subnet on the client, router, and server are all /24.

Comment: I checked in `netstat`, and everything looks normal there too. `192.168.50.228     client:address  UHLWIi      en0    951`

Comment: That’s just the ARP cache entry, not (really) a route. Please add the full output of `netstat -rn -f inet` to your question. If the problem isn’t there, I’m out of ideas. One thing remains abundantly clear: Your router is not to blame (although it probably has bugs and should not change the IP addresses either way), but instead your Mac is directing traffic where it should not.